# building a project with RhoStudio and then extending it with using xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, rhomobile, rhodes

I have created a simple application using rhoStudio for iphone and then converted that project to xcode compatible.

I can see all my project in Xcode.
Now I want to add more functionality to the project and I want it to be done using the objective C i.e in Xcode, not form RhoStudio

How can I do it.

Is this possible that we can do half of the development using RhoStudio and half of it using Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer but in a different way, we can extend the rhomobile project further using xcode, but the thing is we cannot change the code that was created by the rhoStudio.

Now for the extension i found this wonderful tutorial at rhoMobile website.

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions#rewriting-the-generated-native-extension-source-code-for-iphone